# How to make div come under another div

Tags: html, css

How can I make DIV "sideBottom" go under "SideTop" and "console " go under "Main"?

This is how it looks at the moment:

[image: Current page layout]

HTML/CSS:

```css
*{
    padding : 0;
    margin : 0;
    border : 0;
}
body{
    background-image : url(' bi-background-cubes.png ');
    background-attachment : fixed;
    background-size : 100% auto;
}
.blended_grid{
    display : block;
    width : 1370px;
    overflow : auto;
    margin : 50px auto 0 auto;
}
.pageHeader{
    background-color : rgba(6,67,0,0.4);
    float : left;
    clear : none;
    height : 70px;
    width : 1370px;
}
.sideTop{
    background-color : rgba(0,2,227,0.4);
    float : left;
    clear : none;
    height : 430px;
    width : 260px;
}
.main{
    background-color : rgba(171,0,161,0.4);
    float : left;
    clear : none;
    height : 600px;
    width : 680px;
}
.tableInput{
    background-color : rgba(156,141,0,0.4);
    float : left;
    clear : none;
    height : 350px;
    width : 400px;
}
.tableOutput{
    clear : none;
    float : left;
    position : relative;
    width : 400px;
    height : 350px;
    background-color : rgba(0,115,97,0.4);
}
.sideBottom{
    clear : none;
    float : left;
    position : relative;
    width : 260px;
    height : 270px;
    background-color : rgba(255,0,10,0.4);
}
.console{
    background-color : lightgreen;
    float : left;
    clear : none;
    height : 100px;
    width : 680px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blended_grid">
  <div class="pageHeader">`
    <h1> pageHeader</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="sideTop">
    <h1> SideTop </h1>
  </div>
    
  <div class="main">
    <h1> Main </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="tableInput">
    <h1>tableInput</h1>
  </div>
    
  <div class="tableOutput">
    <h1> tableOutput</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="sideBottom">
    <h1> SideBottom</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="console">
    <h1>  Console</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you change the HTML? I'd add three HTML wrappers, one around each column, and update your CSS appropriately.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "go under". Are you referring to the z-index stacking order, or the actual div ordering on the page.

Comment: Yea the html should definitely be updated to make this easier on yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the floats, add some wrapping divs, and use flex:

I assume this is what you want:  https://jsfiddle.net/znvuepLq/

Here's a good resource for flex:  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

HTML/CSS:

```css
*{
  padding : 0;
  margin : 0;
  border : 0;
}
body{
  background-image : url(' bi-background-cubes.png ');
  background-attachment : fixed;
  background-size : 100% auto;
}
.blended_grid{
  width : 1370px;
  overflow : auto;
  margin : 50px auto 0 auto;
}
.content{
  display: flex;
}
.pageHeader{
  background-color : rgba(6,67,0,0.4);
  height : 70px;
  width : 1370px;
}
.sideTop{
  background-color : rgba(0,2,227,0.4);
  height : 430px;
  width : 260px;
}
.main{
  background-color : rgba(171,0,161,0.4);
  height : 600px;
  width : 680px;
}
.tableInput{
  background-color : rgba(156,141,0,0.4);
  height : 350px;
  width : 400px;
}
.tableOutput{
  width : 400px;
  height : 350px;
  background-color : rgba(0,115,97,0.4);
}
.sideBottom{
  width : 260px;
  height : 270px;
  background-color : rgba(255,0,10,0.4);
}
.console{
  background-color : lightgreen;
  height : 100px;
  width : 680px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blended_grid">
  <div class="pageHeader">`
    <h1> pageHeader</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div>
      <div class="sideTop">
        <h1> SideTop </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="sideBottom">
        <h1> SideBottom</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="main">
        <h1> Main </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="console">
        <h1>  Console</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="tableInput">
        <h1>tableInput</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="tableOutput">
        <h1> tableOutput</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! that is exactly what i wanted! Just brilliant.... you are a Star *.

Answer (score 0):

try using z-index.
it determines what div / object is rendered first. 
:)

Comment: Good idea, but you should include an example in case he's a visual learner. A link to MDN's article on z-indexing would also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, it was great to know about z-index .